# Configure ocamlopt so gdb can get source location information

Tags: gdb, ocaml

The native OCaml compiler exposes options that control whether debug information is emitted. For instance `-g` controls whether to record information needed to reconstruct exception backtraces. Is there an option to emit the debug information that would be needed for `gdb` to associate breakpoints with source information like file name and line number?

I don't think OCaml is, at present, a fully supported language for `gdb` and it isn't possible to pretty-print values or evaluate OCaml expressions. That is okay, I'm just wondering how to configure the `ocamlopt` compiler or `gdb` in such a way that `gdb` can find the source file. Ideally I'd like to be able to see both the OCaml sources and the C source files that implement OCaml runtime when they are present (i.e. when building a compiler by hand rather than through OPAM).

For instance,

```
(* hello.ml *)

let main () =
  Printf.printf "hi there\n%!";;

let () = main ()
```

compiled using `corebuild hello.native`, produces a symlink to an executable, `hello.native`.

and then, when starting `gdb`:

```
(gdb) file hello.native
Reading symbols from hello.native...done.
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x405580: file main.c, line 32.
Starting program: /home/g/ws/tmp/ocaml/hello/hello.native 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Temporary breakpoint 1, main (argc=0x1, argv=0x7fffffffdaf8) at main.c:32 
32  main.c: No such file or directory.
```

We can see that it was unable to determine where the file is.

When you hit `C-x a` and switch `gdb` to tui mode, then the message `[ No Source Available ]` is visible in the top pane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `dir` directive in `gdb` to point it to the place where is the source code of the OCaml runtime, e.g.,

```
(gdb) dir ~/warehouse/ocaml/byterun/
Source directories searched: /home/ivg/warehouse/ocaml/byterun:$cdir:$cwd
(gdb) l
27      #endif
28
29      CAMLextern void caml_main (char_os **);
30
31      #ifdef _WIN32
32      CAMLextern void caml_expand_command_line (int *, wchar_t ***);
33
34      int wmain(int argc, wchar_t **argv)
35      #else
36      int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

Few more tips. You can link your program with the debugging runtime, e.g.,

```
ocamlopt -runtime-variant x -g hello.ml -o hello
```

It won't have the source code embedded though.

Also, OCaml has quite a good support for gdb, you can step, backtrace, and even observe the source code. The only problem is that names are usually mangled, so it is hard to set up a breakpoint. However, you can use `objdump` to reverse engineer your file. It is easy if it is built with the `-g` option:

```
$ objdump -S hello | grep hello.ml -A 10
(* hello.ml *)

let main () =
  404a70:       48 8d 1d 81 a6 24 00    lea    0x24a681(%rip),%rbx        # 64f0f8 <camlHello__5>
  404a77:       48 8d 05 da b3 24 00    lea    0x24b3da(%rip),%rax        # 64fe58 <camlPervasives>
  Printf.printf "hi there\n%!";;
  404a7e:       48 8b 80 d0 00 00 00    mov    0xd0(%rax),%rax
  404a85:       e9 66 ae 01 00          jmpq   41f8f0 <camlPrintf__fprintf_1294>
  404a8a:       66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)

0000000000404a90 <camlHello__entry>:
```

Comment: The `-runtime-variant d` option is great (maybe it used to be called `-runtime-variant x`?). I didn't know about it until I read your post and it just helped me solve a nasty bug in a complex FFI. Thanks!